# To set and return a variable value without creating an additional variable

Tags: javascript, variables

Is it possible to compact the function below so there is no variable created?

```
    var flag=true;
    //...
    my.flagValue=function(){
        var f=flag;
        flag=false;
        return(f);
    };
```

Basically, to set and return (the previous) value at the same time.

Comment: Why put the return value into `()`?

Comment: No, it's not possible in general.

Comment: @OliverWeiler To give me the impression that I know what the code will do exactly. But seriously, I've always preferred this style. Just me. Ignore it if it makes you barf.

Comment: +1 because I might steal this for use as a technical interview question sometime. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, normally there's no way to return something before setting it. But in this *specific* case, you can use some magic to pull it off. Though your original code is far more readable and maintainable:

```
my.flagValue = function () {
    return (flag && !(flag = false));
};
```

If flag is true, then it will perform like this:

```
return (true && !(flag = false)); //!(flag = false) is true, so true is returned.
```

If flag is false, then it will perform like this:

```
return (false && !(flag = false)); //obviously returns false.
```

Though, I really do encourage you not to do this. It's obscure and requires a bit of logic parsing to sort out. I just wanted to demonstrate that it's possible to do what you're looking to do in this specific case.

Comment: +1 for finding a solutions that "works" and for recommending not to use it ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Glad you agree. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just flipping the value of `flag` between `true` and `false` then this might work for you:

```
my.flagValue=function(){
    return !(flag = newValue);
};
```

This will set `flag` to `newValue` and return opposite value from the function.

Comment: OP wants to return the previous value though, not the new value.

Comment: Now what this does is returning the opposite of the new value, not the previous value.

Comment: Sure, it will only work if he is flipping the values back and forth - I don't think there is a general solution that doesn't use an intermediate  variable

Comment: This will only work in the case where `flag` is boolean, the last statement should be `return !(flag = !flag)`. That sets `flag` to the opposite of its current value, then returns the opposite of that (which is the original value). Probably worth +5 for obfuscation alone. :-)

Comment: @codebox No "general" solution. But my answer works for this particular question. Give it a read. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well, If I understood the question correctly :)

```
   my.flagValue=function(){
             return flag ? !flag : flag ;
          };
```

Comment: No, the OP wants to also change the value of `flag`;